# how can i achieve the below output (python)

Tags: python, data-manipulation

Could you please help me reshape the data as below:

input DF

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'1': [14561,'X store','Sales Quantity',1],
                   '2': [14561,'X store','Net Sales',2],
                   '3': [16534,'Y store','Sales Quantity',2],
                   '4': [16534,'Y store','Net Sales',1]})
```

I would like to achieve the below op

```
store_code  store_name  sales_total    net_sales_total
14561       X store           1                     2
16534       Y store           2                     1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ['store_code', 'store_name', 'sales', 'value']
df = df.pivot_table(index=['store_code','store_name'], 
               columns = 'sales', 
               values='value', 
               aggfunc = np.sum)

df.columns = ['net_sales_total', 'sales_total']
```

**Output**

```
                         net_sales_total    sales_total
store_code  store_name      
14561       X store          2                  1
16534       Y store          1                  2
```

Just notice that `store_code` and `store_name` in this case are `multi index` DataFrame's

Answer (score 0):

df.unique and transpose

```
df=df.transpose()
for i in df.columns:
    print(df[i].unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.transpose()
print('store_code' + str(df[0].unique()))
print('store_name' + str(df[1].unique()))
print('sales_total' + str(df[2].unique()))
print('net_sales_total' + str(df[3].unique()))
```